# Remove rows from dataframe with boolean values

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe `a`:

```
> a <- cbind(c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
> a
           [,1]     [,2]
  [1,]    FALSE    TRUE
  [2,]    FALSE    FALSE
  [3,]    TRUE     FALSE
  [4,]    TRUE     TRUE
```

I want to remove all rows whose first column value and second column value is false. Note that I do have some other, non-boolean columns.

Comment: What do you mean "Note that I do have some other, non-boolean columns." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to keep each row which contains at least one `TRUE` column:

```
keep <- a[,1] | a[,2]
a <- a[keep, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rowSums.

```
 a[(rowSums(a[,1:2])!=0),]
```

Comment: This outputs "FALSE FALSE" row, too. Maybe you meant this: `a[rowSums(a[,1:2],)>=1,]`